# Can I list objects in an enum in Java?

Tags: java, oop, enums

I would like to know if i can get this to work:

```
public enum Items {
    Weapon starterBow = new Weapon("Starter Bow", AttackSpeed.SLOW),
    Weapon advancedBow = new Weapon("Advanced Bow", AttackSpeed.MEDIUM),
    Weapon goldenBow = new Weapon("Golden Bow", AttackSpeed.FAST);
}
```

I want to access it like this:

```
Items.starterBow.getName()
```

(Weapons have a getName() Method)

This code snippet at the beginning is giving me errors, but is there any other way to list Objects like this? (Without creating a new class)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum`s syntactically act as regular classes, so you can have fields, methods and constructors.

The difference is that you specifiy the instances of the class during the enum declaration. These instances are created by the jvm and cannot be created in any other way.

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
public enum Items {
  //Fields
  String name;
  AttackSpeed attackSpeed;

  //constructor:
  Items(String name, AttackSpeed attkSpd) {
    this.name = name;
    this.attackSpeed = attkSpd;
  }

  //methods:
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  //listing the instances and calling the constructor:
  StarterBow ("Starter Bow", AttackSpeed.SLOW),
  AdvancedBow ("Advanced Bow", AttackSpeed.MEDIUM),
  GoldenBow ("Golden Bow", AttackSpeed.FAST);
}
```